# Object must implement IConvertible

Tags: asp.net, sqldataadapter

> Object must implement IConvertible.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.

Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

> Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Object must implement
>   IConvertible.
>
> Error Detail Line 279:
>   da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Total", SqlDbType.Int).Value =
>   txttotal.Text; Line 280:        con1.Open(); Line 281:
>   da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

Code:

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("Insert Into customer_order(ProductID,product_Name,Product_Type,Weight,Unit_Price,No_Of_Master_Pack,Master_Pack_Price,Quantity,Total)VALUES(@ProductID,@product_Name,@Product_Type,@Weight,@Unit_Price,@No_Of_Master_Pack,@Master_Pack_Price,@Quantity,@Total)", con1);
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ProductID",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value=DropDownList3.SelectedItem;
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@product_Name",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value=DropDownList2.SelectedItem;
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Product_Type", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DropDownList1.SelectedItem;
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Weight",SqlDbType.Int).Value=txtwgt.Text;
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Unit_Price",SqlDbType.Int).Value=txtmrpsinglepack.Text;
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@No_Of_Master_Pack",SqlDbType.Int).Value=txtnoofmasterpack.Text;
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Master_Pack_Price",SqlDbType.Int).Value=txtmrpmaster.Text;
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Quantity",SqlDbType.Int).Value=txtquantity.Text;
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Total", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txttotal.Text;
con1.Open();
da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ListControl.SelectedItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selecteditem.aspx) returns a `ListItem` - and it doesn't make much sense for the value of a parameter to be a list item itself, but instead the item's value or text. You probably want something like:

```
da.InsertCommand.Parameters
  .Add("@ProductID",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text;
```

or

```
da.InsertCommand.Parameters
  .Add("@ProductID",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Value;
```

Comment: Thank You Jon Skeet Its Working

Answer (score 2):

use `DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text` or `DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Value` to assign it to a `Value`.