# How to Insert Time through TextBox

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have database in SQL Server 2008, I want to insert time as (`11:05`) through a textbox while the data type of my table is `DATETIME`.

I'm using this code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=NOMAN-PC;Initial Catalog=parking;Integrated Security=True");        

string qry = "Insert Into vehicle_log values('" +DropDownList_vehType.SelectedItem+ "','" + TextBox_RegNo.Text + "',@Time_in)";        
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con);

TimeSpan Time_in = TimeSpan.Parse(TextBox_timeIn.Text + ":" + TextBox_timemin.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Time_in" ,System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime ).Value = Time_in;

con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

on click button following error appears:

> Object must implement IConvertible.

I am new to ASP.NET and SQL Server, I will be grateful for your guidance.

Regards

Comment: looks like you can find the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754413/object-must-implement-iconvertible)

Answer (score 0):

First set time variable then put $now anywhere you want to display time at for example

```
$now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
echo $now;
```

Answer (score 0):

1). Try to change **DropDownList_vehType.SelectedItem** on **DropDownList_vehType.SelectedItem.Text**

2). You **MUST** use parameters to avoid injection

3). You can use AddWithValue method instead of Add (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx)